# The type initializer for 'ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw exception

Tags: azure-role-environment

I have custome azure utility dll that has one method to read configuration values from `ServiceConfiguration` and also has fallback code to read from `AppSettings` from `web.config` in case `RoleEntironment` is not running .
This DLLs works fine with Azure WCF project runnning on local and production cloud environment.

For some reason I am hosting this WCF service on Rackspace server on IIS.

On my local machine IIS, WCF service works fine but on Rackspace it crashes with following error:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception.

I have copied `WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll`, `Diagnostics.dll` and `StorageClient.dll` in bin on rackspace. Still it gives same error.

I have also tried copying `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">` to `Web.config`, still it does not work.

Any idea? Am I missing more cloud DLLs or some more configuration is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through this pain recently. And it ended up being a mismatched version of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics dll in the Azure project file causing the problem. If you have local working copy and a successful deploy from a previous version you can copy the deployed files from the Azure VM and compare them to your local set (it was the Worker Role that was failing for me). If not check the versions to make sure the version being referenced is included in the deploy with CopyLocal set to true.

Comment: Thank you, it pointed us in the right direction. In our case, it was a similar issue with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by adding useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" in config file

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```